# Prototypal inheritance javascript using variables in different functions

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I am making a Hangman game to improve my knowledge of prototypal inheritance.

I am completely confused as to why on of the variables `this.guesses` is not visible in the prototypal functions. I have tried to play around with every different combination I could think of.

My code is as follows:

```
function Hangman () {
    this.token;
    this.guesses = 7;
}

Hangman.prototype.startGame = function() {
    $.ajax({
            url:"http://hangman-api.herokuapp.com/hangman",
            type: "POST",
            data: {}
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            Hangman.token = data.token;
            $(".hangman-word").text(data.hangman);
        }).fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
    });
};

Hangman.prototype.takeGuess = function(token, letter){
    var letter = $("#letter").val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://hangman-api.herokuapp.com/hangman",
        type:"PUT",
        data: {"token": Hangman.token, "letter": letter }
    }).done(function(data) {
            Hangman.guesses = Hangman.guesses - 1;
            console.log(Hangman.guesses)
        }).fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
    });
        console.log(Hangman.token);     
}


var hangman = new Hangman;
hangman.startGame();
```

The really strange thing is that `Hangman.token` is visible in the `takeGuess` function but `Hangman.guesses` is not. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `guesses` member is an **instance member** and you cannot call it as static.

That member is declared on the constructor, so, it will be available only as `this.guesses`.

`Hangman.token` exists because you declare it as static member on the `startGame` member...

I think that there are some inconsistencies in your script... I'll try to explain you which are the differences between **static** and **instances** member in javascript through an example:

> Consider that with the [ES6 specification](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/), the implementation of classes it's a bit different.

In javascript class-like programming, each member declared on the `prototype` object should be assumed as `instance member`, so, each instance of that class will inherit these members.

```js
var Person = (function() {
  function Person() {}

  Person.prototype.sayHello = function() { alert('Hello ' + this.name ); };
  Person.prototype.name = 'Foo';

  
  return Person;
})();

var hitmands = new Person();
hitmands.sayHello();
```

Otherwise, each member declared outside from the prototype object will be assumed as `static member`.

```js
var Person = (function() {
  function Person() {}

  Person.sayHello = function() { alert('Hello ' + Person.name ); };
  Person.name = 'Foo';

  
  return Person;
})();

var hitmands = new Person();

try { hitmands.sayHello(); } catch(e) { console.log(e.name, e); }

// but you can use
Person.sayHello();
```

Finally, I suggest you to have a look at this resource https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Member_variable

Comment: The problem is here is when I reference `this.token` and `this.guesses` is that `this.guesses` is undefined when I try and use it in the `takeGuess` function